# Hi when i create contact us form in Django this integrity error shows

Tags: python, django, model

[Here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M23q.png)

**My code is**

```
def contacts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        desc = request.POST.get('desc')
        contact = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone=phone, desc=desc, date=datetime.today())
        contact.save()
    return render(request, 'contacts.html')
```

**and my model code is**

from django.db import models

## Create your models here.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    desc = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: The name is not submitted in the POST request. This is one (of the many) reasons to use a form that does proper validation.

Comment: You can use PostCreativeView/CreativeView

Answer (score 0):

Error tell you exactly what's going on.

`name` field in Contact can't be empty (null/None). If you want some fields to be not required in form then you can add `null=True`, `blank=True`

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=122, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    desc = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```